# How to have multiple WHERE values in mysqli_query?

Tags: php, where-clause

How would I use multiple values in the WHERE of a mysqli_query??

ex.

```
mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT post_title, post_content, post_date FROM posts WHERE post_id = 3013, 4140, 6850")
```

Is that the correct way to use multiple WHERE values? or...?

Comment: Please use the search. This is first of all a SQL question independent to the database client library used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `IN`

```
WHERE post_id IN (3013, 4140, 6850)
```

which is the same with

```
WHERE post_id = 3013 OR
      post_id = 4140 OR
      post_id = 6850
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IN` clause.

```
mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT post_title, post_content, post_date FROM posts WHERE post_id IN (3013, 4140, 6850)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`:

```
mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT post_title, post_content, post_date FROM posts WHERE post_id IN (3013, 4140, 6850)")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the documentation:

[select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html)

And you seperate your where clauses with `AND` or `OR`